# Anyone got any book recommendations for the derivation of the Wigner formulation of quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, wigner-transform

Preferably one that starts from classical mechanics and derives the theory from that

Comment: @Valter  He means the [phase-space formulation of QM](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf). But he thinks of quantization as a derivable map, I'm not sure why...

Comment: There is a [WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation) on the subject, but not with too many books in its references. Detail-oriented students like W. Schleich's [text](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/3527602976), but if you like concision, our booklet linked above is an option.

Comment: In Yourgrau & van der Merwe:  "Perspectives in Quantum Theory; Essays in Honor of Alfred Lande" Wigner wrote a chapter with the title: "Quantum-Mechanical Distribution Functions Revisited" which very clearly describes his ideas.